# Anime-identification: Boy summons or controls giant robot with a knife

Tags: story-identification, anime

I saw this anime in the late '90s on TV, but I believe it's from 80's.
Boy summons or controls robot with a knife (seems it was combat-like knife, Ka-Bar or similar).
But inside of that knife is some kind of complicated control device.
And then that boy fights with some kind of invader robots in space.
And obviously some bad guys try to dissect that knife and gain control of robot.

I understand that's not the clearest description, but it was more than 20 years ago. This anime is bugging me from time to time, so I hope someone could help me to identify it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the anime you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Could it be Tobikage aka Ninja Robots?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Can you provide a link to a view of the knife-like control device, or a screenshot of it?  It would also be good if you could provide a bit more description of the show, especially since the embedded video doesn't create any searchable text and the video may someday be taken down.